# CloudBees and DoS Protection/Blacklisting

Tags: java, cloudbees, paas, ddos, blacklist

Does CloudBees offer anything in the way of DoS protection or IP blacklisting? I'm wondering what the recommended practices are for protecting CloudBees apps from these kinds of attacks, and don't see anything in their [developer docs](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/) that indicates this is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ins't any platform provided feature to address this. Monitoring application traffic will let you detect them, but not protect against DoS. This would require a dedicated NGinX module, I don't know one.